# Android Emulator after updating to ADT 20 no longer automatically rotates screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt, autorotate

Everything was good until I updated to ADT 20 yesterday, now when I rotate screen with CTRL-F11, screen rotates, but application (ANDROID) remains in portrait mode.

So my question is it possible to either solve this problem and make it rotate or downgrade to ADT 19?

PS: Checked on 2.3.3 and 4.1 images, dev platform is Mac OS X 10.7.4

PPS: The only way I was able to downgrade is to look to my Time Machine backup and copy Eclipse and Platform tools folder to my Mac

Comment: did your code work on device ?

Comment: It's possible that it is a bug... these updates were released very recently. [Report Bugs](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html)

Comment: its not even code, i just running pure emulator from AVD manager. Screen is rotated, content is not, even for Android's embedded apps :(

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but have you checked in the emulator's settings? :)

Comment: @BojanRadivojevicBomber yes, I've checked, both inside "autorotate", and outside hw.accelerometer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, just add the property "Keyboard Support-->yes" in the emulators properties and that fixs the problem. Hopes it helps.