# Android emulator - Screen rotation

Tags: android, android-emulator, rotation, screen, emulation

I would like to test the rotation of a phone on the emulator, I see everywhere that we have to use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** but it only rotates the image of the emulator and does not launch a configuration change event or redraw the activity.

Here is what I have with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** :

[image: emulator rotation]

So, what do I have to use to simulate a real rotation ?

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093208/3621912

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Nicolas Jafelle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265418/android-emulator-after-updating-to-adt-20-no-longer-automatically-rotates-screen), you can try to add the property "Keyboard Support-->yes" in the emulator settings. That helped me.

PS: it will also allow for your emulator to get input from your keyboard. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235370/android-emulator-doesnt-take-keyboard-input-sdk-tools-rev-20)

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer??? The question is how to get a "true" rotation as what would happen on a real phone, not how to use the keyboard.

Comment: Because it is the bug in ADT and without this HW Keyboard trick it doesn't work. Even in ADT 21 that was just released. See this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34237

Comment: similarly to the above solution, you can do this by adding "hw.keyboard=yes" to config.ini of the desired emulator

Comment: I already had keyboard support enabled, it only change the screen of emulator, but videos, pictures,native apps doesn't get the proper rotation.

Answer (score 50):

Also you can do:

disable accelerometer controlling rotation - just do this once

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

rotate landscape:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1
```

rotate portrait:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0
```

rotate upside down landscape:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system  --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:3
```

rotate upside down portrait:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system  --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:2
```

If you have WRITE_SETTINGS permission you can write thru the content provider in java code as well.

Comment: Today I try the command with latest Android SDK. The insert command change to update. And the complete command is now "./adb shell content update --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0". Well, just remind myself.

Answer (score 5):

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html this should do it

did you also support portrait and landscape mode

Comment: did you set the application to work on both landscape and portrait?

Comment: I didn't specified it on the manifest, so that Android itself manage the rotation by destroying and recreating the activity on real devices. But it doesn't work on the amulator.

Comment: so you want the android to recreate the destroying and recreating? Sorry, I am not positive on what your asking

Comment: When the phone rotates, the current activity is destroyed and the same activity is created. This is the default behavior. But in the emulator, I don't know how to do that. Ctrl+F11 only change the disposition of the emulator. You can see it on the image of my first post, the default calculator number aren't turned properly.

Comment: Is the app supported for both landscape and portrait orientation?

Comment: The rotation works on my phone. I don't think that I have to allow the rotation in the manifest ?

Comment: You have to, just to insure the same effect I believe

Comment: This doesn't seem answered. It doesn't appear its truly rotating like a real phone would. It doesn't destroy/create like KPath001 said.

Comment: it doesn't seemed answered to me either. I guess the resolution for now is to just not depend on the emulator for this. or, if you must, test that your app works by only doing "android:screenOrientation="landscape" in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

this just doesn't work in 2.3 emulators, if that's what ur using

see here:

[Android - Emulator in landscape mode, screen does not rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394447/android-emulator-in-landscape-mode-screen-does-not-rotate)

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as you and turned the "auto-rotate screen" option on in the AVD. Worked like a charm.